# Increasing the rate of broadcast intent receiver

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using an broadcast receiver for Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED. 
Rate at which I receive this intent in my application is every 5 sec. But I want to increase this rate as fast as possible.

I dont know If this is possible or not.
Help me if it is possible.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The battery level doesn't change that dramatically within a short period of time.

Comment: I am not interested in battery level, I want to record voltage and current value as fast as possible.(my tab has a current sensor too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible.  The reason is really in the class name, its a receiver.  When you register a receiver it has an exposed method which is called whenever the system detects the ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED intent.  The rate at which you receive this is based purely on the rate at which the system broadcasts the event.